# Standard way to define rules for using an API, for a dynamic UI perhaps

Tags: java, json, rest, api-design

Is there an common way to define the rules for the use of an API within the API itself?

For example, an API for booking a roof repair could need to know if the roof is below 3 meters, between 3 and 10 meters, or over 10 meters. But you want the UI to know that currently if a consumer chooses "over 10 meters" the request is going to be rejected so they know to end the customers journey in an appropriate manner rather than taking the customer through the rest of the questions before trying to submit the api.

Something like this maybe:

```
"roofHeight": {
    "type": "enum",
    "acceptedValues": {
        "LOW": "Under 3 meters",
        "MEDIUM": "Between 3 and 10 meters"
    },
    "rejectedValues": {
        "HIGH": "Over 10 meters"
    },
    "description": "Height of roof."
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You are perhaps talking about the API documentation and contracts.You can refer the swagger API documentation for this activity.
https://swagger.io/docs/